# calculate value & display negative number ( if applicable )

Tags: php, negative-number

OK so in the DB table I have 2 cols & values
Lets say 
open = 1.23450 & close = 1.23400

now here is the PHP code that I am trying to use for the calculation

```
 $pips = abs($value['close'] - $value['open'])*1;
```

This should return a value of -0.0005
However it just simply returns value 0 when I echo $pips

Comment: I think storing these values as 123450 and 123400 would be better. Floating point arithmetic does not yield accurate results.

Comment: is number of digit after the decimal fixed ( 5 digits ? )

Comment: Its storing an accurate value which would require a decimal point so I can't
and fixed value of 5 decimal spaces
* just had to go check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If number of digits after the decimal are fixed ( say 5 digits precision)

```
 $pips = abs($value['close']*100000 - $value['open']*100000);
 $pips = $pips/100000;
```

Comment: You code gives me Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
$pips = abs($value['close']*100000 - $value['open']*100000); // This line

Comment: @ChrisYates No. I am simply assuming $value['close'] and $value['open'] are valid floating point values. I dont know how are you getting them from mysql query.

Comment: Just a simple select * as im testing at the moment
i have them stored as float

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `prices`");
$value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

Comment: code works think my problem was cached :) Many thanks

Comment: glad to know that

Comment: another thing i was wondering ..
lets assume close = 1.223
and open = 1.2236

so obviously its lost a value of 0.006 which I wanted to be translated as -6
however it returns 
0.00059999999999985
I tried using round($pips) but that rounded it up to 60 .. which is weird

Comment: Yes, the solution is based on assumptions that you have fixed length precision. In case you don't have fixed length precision, pad zeros at the end of number with lower precision, use stripos to determine the position.of decimal and then apply the above logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157306/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-tarun).

Answer (score 0):

You are using abs() which returns absolute positive value of a number so you need to multiply by "-1" (minus) and as suggested floating points aren't so good in PHP so better calculate the `$pips` as a whole number first then dividing  depending on the number of digits after the point.